# Build combobox list on values in range skip empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have combobox on worksheet "MAIN". Combobox name is SignatureBox. I would like to build combobox list based on values on worksheet "Contact database" in range A55:A80. In range A55:A80 I have formulas that are like `=IF(C7="";"";C7)` so they are returning empty cells that I want to skip and build the list only with available values. For some reason my current code not working all the time. On the second click on combobox list is getting messed up and all the value are doubled. What might be the problem?

It seems to work with `Worksheet_Change` but then I have to go on Sheet `Contact database` and make a change. It is getting messed up with `Worksheet_Calculate`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim RngCom As Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").SignatureBox.Clear
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact database")
    For Each RngCom In .Range(.Range("A55"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If RngCom.Value <> vbNullString Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").SignatureBox.AddItem RngCom.Value
    Next RngCom
End With
End Sub
```

In combobox Properties I have LinckedCell setted as `'Contact database'!R4`

Comment: Which sheet module is this code in?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have tried it in different sheets and it works only with `Worksheet_Change`but not with `Worksheet_Calculate`. Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would go in the worksheet module for sheet "Contact database":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range, sb As Object

    'any changes in Col C ?
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then

        Set sb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").SignatureBox
        sb.Clear

        'add non-blank values
        For Each c In me.Range(me.Range("A55"), me.Range("A" & me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Len(c.Value)>0 then sb.AddItem c.Value
        Next c

    End If

End Sub
```